# which path should be selected as JAVA_HOME and PATH for java in centOS

Tags: java, path, java-home

When i go inside /usr/lib/jvm, i see below folders, which one should be selected as JAVA_HOME and PATH? I am using CentOS. Thanks.

**java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.el7_7.x86_64**
**jre-1.8.0**
**jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.el7_7.x86_64**
**jre**
**jre-1.8.0-openjdk  jre-openjdk**

Answer (score 0):

Confirm Environment variable value.

**JAVA_HOME**

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.el7_7.x86_64
```

**PATH**

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

or 
put as

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.el7_7.x86_64/bin
```

**CLASSPATH**

```
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```

Source: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-set-java_home-on-centos-fedora-rhel/